# ASP.NET / SQL parameter issue in a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to access some data from SQL Server in ASP.NET, but I can't get a parameter to pass to a SQL Server stored procedure. The parameter is located in the URL (i.e. `www.company.com/ImportantManager.aspx?id=Jones,%Bob`), as I only want Bob Jones' results displayed.

`NiceMgr_Total` is the stored procedure. I have seen many different responses to similar questions on here and the Microsoft forums, but I think the stored procedure might be messing it up (the `@manager` parameter specifically - the other parameters seem to work fine).

I've tried it multiple ways, and I'm getting an assortment of parser errors and "parameter not found" errors. Thanks for your help.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" 
       AutoGenerateRows="False" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Manager" HeaderText="Manager" SortExpression="Manager" 
            ItemStyle-Width="41px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="tableheader3" ItemStyle-CssClass="tabledata2" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>" 
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="DECLARE @PerDate VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
    SET @CurrentDate = (SELECT MAX([MostRecent]) FROM sameDB.dbo.RecentDate)
    SET @PerDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentDate,120) AS VARCHAR(50))
    EXEC [NiceMgr_Total] @date1=@PerDate, @date2=@PerDate, @manager=@MgrName">

    <selectparameters>
        <asp:querystringparameter name="MgrName" DBtype="String" 
             QueryStringField="<%Response.Write(Request.QueryString.Item("id"))%>" />
    </selectparameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few issues with your approach - try these steps:

1. you need to specify **just** the stored procedure name in your `SelectCommand`
2. you need to put **all** parameters into the `<SelectParameters>` collection
3. ***please:*** if you have dates - then use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes and don't constantly convert back and forth to and from strings!
4. you need to tell your select command that it's a stored procedure (and not inline SQL text)
5. for your `<QueryStringParameter>` - you only need to specify the **name** of the query string element - the `SqlDataSource` will go read the value itself

You need to try something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="dbo.NiceMgr_Total"   <!-- *JUST* the name! -->
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">   <!-- tell it's a stored procedure! -->
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter name="MgrName" DbType="String" QueryStringField="id" />
        <!-- specify *ALL* parameters here! -->
        <asp:Parameter Name="date1" DbType="DATETIME" />   
        <asp:Parameter Name="date2" DbType="DATETIME" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, of course, you'll need to find some way to specify the `date1` and `date2` parameters before the `SelectCommand` of your `SqlDataSource` gets executed ....

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
  QueryStringField="<%Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString.Item("id")))%>" />
```

You may need to decode the querystring before it can be parameterized.

Comment: The `QueryStringField` should contain only the **field name** in the query string - not the value specified on the query string!